# How do I create a subclass of boost::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, subclass

I'm trying to subclass boost::unordered_map (so I can catch exceptions without having the exception-catching logic clutter my program). I have successfully wrapped boost::unordered_map, but I wanted to try creating a subclass.

Anyway, I'm having trouble determining the correct subclass syntax.

The following does not work:

```
template<typename Key, typename Mapped, typename Hash = boost::hash<Key>,
         typename Pred = std::equal_to<Key>,
         typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, Mapped>> >
class unordered_map : public boost::unordered_map<typename Key, typename Mapped, typename Hash = boost::hash<Key>,
                                                  typename Pred = std::equal_to<Key>,
                                                  typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, Mapped>> >
{

};
```

Comment: The standard containers are not designed to be used as base classes, so the usual answer is "don't even try."

Comment: Good to know.  Actually, searching for *why* this was a bad idea gave me much more insight than searching for *how* to do it.

Comment: You can wrap it though

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

template<typename Key, typename Mapped, typename Hash = boost::hash<Key>,
         typename Pred = std::equal_to<Key>,
         typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, Mapped> > >
class my_unordered_map : public boost::unordered_map<Key, Mapped, Hash,Pred,Alloc>
{

};

void main(){
    my_unordered_map<int,int> kk;
}
```

Comment: as @Bartek remark , you'd better wrap unordered_map into another class